# regex for appscript, case insensitivy not working

Tags: javascript, regex

Below I am trying to use regex to get the occurrence of certain strings.

```
  var value = "ab-2123 AB-332";
  // "i" is for case insensitive
  var regExp = new RegExp("(ab)[-][0-9]*", "gi"); 
  var searchedString = regExp.exec(value);
  console.log(searchedString);
```

This only detects `ab-2124` but not `AB-33`. Could some one please help me to figure out the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the match property instead of exec:

```js
var value = "ab-2123 AB-332";
var re = new RegExp("(ab)[-][0-9]*", "gi");
var searchedString = value.match(re);
console.log(searchedString);
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks a lot! Saved me a lot of time looking around! :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a few important typos corrected

`var searchedString regExp.exec(value)` should be `var searchedString = regExp.exec(value)`

`console.log(searched string);` should be `console.log(searchedString);`

---

`regExp.exec()` will only return your first match. If you want multiple, you could use `String.match(regExp)`

```js
let value = "ab-2123 AB-332";

  let regExp = new RegExp("(ab)[-][0-9]*", "gi"); // "i" is for case insensitive
  let searchedString = value.match(regExp);
  console.log(searchedString);
```